# How to speed up and skip from line to line in a txt file in batch

Tags: batch-file

OK I'm going with something easier and smaller

I would like to know how we can make this faster and how to make it skip lines between 1 and 400

I tested it and it only removes the first line, well it ignores the first line and then it prints the rest

I have tried many different versions that I had found here and none worked not sure why, so far this one worked, but it's super slow

My txt file has around 250K lines and when I tested this it took forever 
Then I tested it on 900 lines and it was super fast

here is the script I'm using

```bash
@echo off
setlocal
set file=(99).txt
set lineToDelete=1
(for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%file%" ^|findstr /bv "%lineToDelete%:"') do echo/%%b) > (99)Ready.txt
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I am certain, that I told you [just yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75535789/how-to-make-a-2-code-extraction-also-delete-after#comment133269602_75535789), that working code requiring comment or suggested improvements like this should technically be submitted to Code Review. Is there a particular reason why you are continuing to ignore that advice?

Comment: Please open your Command Prompt window, type `for /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key. You should clearly see that the `/F` option has a `SKIP` parameter. Additionally you could take a look at the output from `more /?`, which also can ignore the first `n` lines!

Comment: @Compo - OK let me try to understand - you said `comment` or `suggested` is there a different place to do this? and I'm not search what you mean by `code review`  - I am still trying to understand the site and all of it's rules, I am not fully aware of how this site works 100%, but I have been trying to learn, like using  ```shell I noticed that you use that  lot so I have been trying to remember this, my apologies for any misunderstandings

Comment: I gave you the Code Review link, directly in my comment, in your last question. Code Review is for things like improving working code, by restructuring, making it more efficient, or simply offering better robustness or speed.

Comment: OH, I had no idea that was a link to that, Thanks I will check it out

Comment: @Compo - question normally when I type I use this `<br>` what do you use that is easier

Comment: Questions about preferred methods of formatting the question are not really pertinent to your issues, and wasting screen realestate on this would technically be off topic. What I'd expect you to be doing right now, is [Edit]ing your question to include your code using the `Skip` parameter, and/or the `more.com` utility, as already advised, if it fails to achieve the intended goal of omitting the first four hundred lines. If it works as intended the use the comment area to inform other readers, and provide pertinent feedback.

Answer (score -1):

if you want a practical solution to quickly reach the goal: install Cygwin and use its Unix tools.

`tail +400`

skips the first 400 lines.

In case you want an academic solution in plain windows ... use power shell, that should be a bit quicker than batches, but there's still a bit of coding required. If it must be CMD batch, live with slow stuff, this kind of coding is way more than Billy boy intended command.com and cmd.exe to deliver.

Comment: I tried `tail` but didn't know I needed to install `Cygwin` but I would like to keep it to batch, without having to install other programs, once this is ready, it will be shared to over 500 computers easy and that would mean I would have to install that to each computer, and I have no idea how to get started with `powershell` I did take a look, and it didn't make no sense, I was totally confused

Comment: Don't bother @JRSantos, there is absolutely no need to install additional programs or packages to perform this task. PowerShell already has this functionality, and is already integrated into all modern Windows Operating Systems. Also, if you really wanted to utilize Unix commands and utilities, you'd be better advised to look into downloading and using WSL2.